# Обособление слова "никак"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять слово "никак" в таких случаях?

В Нацкорпусе встречаются разные варианты:

> Да ты никак обиделся?
>
> Да ты, никак, умирать собрался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужно ли обособлять слово "никак"?..

Из *"Словаря вводных слов"* Остроумовой и Фрамполь (М., 2009):

> НИКАК, част., разг. Неустойчиво вводное, **решение об обособлении
>   принимает автор…**
>
> Ср.: *Никак, заболела?* (К. Паустовский).  — *Никак заболела?*
>
> **Есть тенденция частицу никак чаще обособлять.**

Answer (score 1):

**Никак** ― здесь частица, не вводное слово, имеет значение неуверенности в вопросительных предложениях.

**Да ты никак обиделся? Да ты никак умирать собрался?**

НИКАК, частица. (в вопросит. предл.). Разг. 1. Употр. для выражения неуверенности, предположительности высказывания; кажется, как будто. Н. гроза? Н. он заболел? Н. кто-то пришёл?